# Setting up a Kibana terms panel for an Elasticsearch field that is a list of strings

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a Kibana dashboard that contains a terms panel to show the number of instances for a particular field (let's call it field1). Field1 is, effectively, a list of strings. Each string usually contains multiple words. Since it's analyzed, Elasticsearch breaks the terms up into separate columns. I need to keep the text together, so I need a not_analyzed version. Here's my attempt to do that with a template, located at ~\config\templates\doc_template.json on a Windows box, which does not seem to be working. Elasticsearch is running as a Windows service.

```
{
    "doc_template": {
        "template": "*",
        "mappings": {
            "Type-*": {
                "properties": {
                    "Field1": {
                        "type": "multi_field",
                        "fields": {
                            "Field1": { "index": "analyzed" },
                            "RawField1": { "index": "not_analyzed" }
                        }                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the terms panel, I expect the necessary field to be either RawField1 or Field1.RawField1, but I've tried other variations including and excluding .raw, with no luck.

New indexes are created daily. Field1 exists in 4 separate types, each of which begin with "Type-". I suspect my attempt at using a wildcard there is problematic, but I'm not sure. All data is being sent to Elasticsearch via NEST in a C# .NET application. Here's the mapping for Field1 as it currently exists for one of the types:

```
{
  "index-2014.12.08" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "Type-1" : {
        "properties" : {
          "Field1" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "Field2" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "Field3" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, the mapping doesn't look like how I expect. What's the best way to remedy this issue?

Comment: What about using `_default_` instead of `Type-*`?

Comment: @Pigueiras: It doesn't seem to work. If I get the new document out, there's only Field1 and no RawField1. I would assume that RawField1 would be a visible field.

Comment: Did you try in a new index? Also remember that the `not_analyzed` data will be in `Field1.RawField1` (because you are using multifields), not in `RawField1`.

Comment: Would I also need .raw in addition Field1.RawField1 for Kibana?

Comment: No! Can you copy in the question what you get when you do `curl -XGET http://.../index/field/_mapping?pretty`? You should see something like: `field1: { type: ..., rawfield: { ... } }`

Comment: I edited the mapping in. I'm trying to keep things as brief as possible in the question while still conveying the problem.

Comment: Do you have the template in your cluster? If you do `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template/` does the template appear?

Comment: It returns a 200 and an empty response. So, that appears to be my issue, then.

Comment: You can try to use `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/template_1` too, instead the config files option.

Comment: Can I know which version of Elasticsearch you are using?

Comment: @JeevaN This question is 4 years old at this point and I'm no longer connected to this project. I won't be able to provide any additional details.